# Apply an 'or' to an inner joined where clause ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Model:

```
class QueueList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :times

  self.today
    joins(:times).where(times: { period_type: 'on', date: Date.today} || times: { period_type: 'from', date: Date.today }) 
  end
end
```

The above model contains a list of times. Because :times can be in two different period_types, I have to apply an "OR" to this query. Is there a way to accomplish the above faulty code without the usage of a string query as I am trying to do in ActiveRecord?

Comment: for now, you'd use the `any_of` gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Arel`](https://github.com/rails/arel) to perform OR queries or the [`ActiverecordAnyOf`](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of) gem.

However, in your case, you could just use inclusion (`IN` statement). For example:

```
.where(period_type: %w(on from), date: Date.today)
```